# From XML SharePoint list to Html Table

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, sharepoint-list

I'm working in a SharePoint List View, with Xsl, the list is formatted like this.

```
<Rows>
   <Row text='text1' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text2' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text3' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text4' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text5' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text6' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text7' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text8' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text9' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text10' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text11' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text12' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text13' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text14' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text15' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text16' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text17' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text18' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text19' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text20' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text21' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text22' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text23' group='group2'/>

   ...
</Rows>
```

I need to be formatted like.

```
<Table>
  <td>
    <ul class='group1'>
      <li>text1</li>
      <li>text2</li>
      <li>text3</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
  <td>
    <ul class='group1'>
      <li>text4</li>
      <li>text5</li>
      <li>text6</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
  <td>
    <ul class='group1'>
     <li>text7</li>
     <li>text8</li>
     <li>text9</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</table>
<Table>
  <td>
    <ul class='group2'>
      <li>text10</li>
      <li>text11</li>
      <li>text12</li>
      <li>text13</li>
      <li>text14</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
    <ul class='group2'>
      <li>text15</li>
      <li>text16</li>
      <li>text17</li>
      <li>text18</li>
      <li>text19</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
    <ul class='group2'>
      <li>text20</li>
      <li>text21</li>
      <li>text22</li>
      <li>text23</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</table>
```

Notice that i need to separate in groups depending on a field, and then on 3 subgroups. I know how to do both things, but separately. I'm using a key to group the rows by @group.
Here is my actual code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="Grouping" match="Row" use="@group" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[count(. | key('Grouping', @group)[1]) = 1]">
      <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Grouping', @group)[position() mod ceiling(count(key('Grouping', @group)) div 3) = 1]" mode="cell"/>
      </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" mode="row">
    <td>
      <ul class="{@group}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::node()[position() &lt; ceiling(count(key('Grouping', @group)) div 3)]"
                   mode="cell" />
      </ul>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" mode="cell">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text" disable-output-escaping="no"/>

        </li>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If i could use the following-sibling::key("Grouping", @group)[bla] instead of node()[bla] i think my problem would be solved.

Please let me know if anything if confusing or not clear enough.

EDIT: Xsl version 1.0, the only one supported by SharePoint

Comment: What is the rule for `ul[@class='group2']`, why are there more than 3 `li` elements each?

Comment: I don't understand your questions, but I'll give it a try, for the first question, this is no actually how i will create the html, but i know how to work with that. There is more than 3 elements, because i don't need to group them in groups of 3, instead i need to divide them in 3 groups, i dont care about the group size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="row-by-group" match="Row" use="@group" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<xsl:for-each select="Rows/Row[count(. | key('row-by-group', @group)[1]) = 1]">
    <table>
        <xsl:variable name="rows-in-group" select="key('row-by-group', @group)" />
        <xsl:variable name="size" select="ceiling(count($rows-in-group) div 3)" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$rows-in-group[position() mod $size = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="start" select="count(preceding-sibling::Row)" />
            <td>
                <ul class="{@group}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$rows-in-group[$start &lt;= count(preceding-sibling::Row) and count(preceding-sibling::Row) &lt; $start + $size]">
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="@text"/></li>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </ul>   
            </td>   
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:for-each>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following input:

```
<Rows>
   <Row text='text1' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text2' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text3' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text4' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text5' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text6' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text7' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text8' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text9' group='group1'/>
   <Row text='text10' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text11' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text12' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text13' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text14' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text15' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text16' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text17' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text18' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text19' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text20' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text21' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text22' group='group2'/>
   <Row text='text23' group='group2'/>
</Rows>
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <table>
      <td>
         <ul class="group1">
            <li>text1</li>
            <li>text2</li>
            <li>text3</li>
         </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
         <ul class="group1">
            <li>text4</li>
            <li>text5</li>
            <li>text6</li>
         </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
         <ul class="group1">
            <li>text7</li>
            <li>text8</li>
            <li>text9</li>
         </ul>
      </td>
   </table>
   <table>
      <td>
         <ul class="group2">
            <li>text10</li>
            <li>text11</li>
            <li>text12</li>
            <li>text13</li>
            <li>text14</li>
         </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
         <ul class="group2">
            <li>text15</li>
            <li>text16</li>
            <li>text17</li>
            <li>text18</li>
            <li>text19</li>
         </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
         <ul class="group2">
            <li>text20</li>
            <li>text21</li>
            <li>text22</li>
            <li>text23</li>
         </ul>
      </td>
   </table>
</html>
```

Note the root element added to the output.

Comment: Let me give it a try, but i think it great, i'll be back to mark this as an answer

Comment: Dude, i f*cking love you, i wasted a whole day yesterday. I marked as an answer, but i cant give you points, I'm sorry (not enough reputation)